# Spresenseで対数計算をするとAttentionが出る

Tags: spresense

Spresenseで音声を取りつつリアルタイム処理をしています．
その中で，logの計算をさせ，配列に格納する場面があるのですが，途中で以下のようなエラーが出てきます．
Spresenseでlogの計算をする際には何か注意点等あるのでしょうか．

```
Attention: module[4][0] attention id[1]/code[6] (objects/media_recorder/audio_recorder_sink.cpp L84)
Attention!! Level 0x1 Code 0x6
```

Comment: エラーメッセージだけでなく、実際のコードも質問に含めた方が回答が付きやすいかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

SDK開発ガイドに Attention Code について記載があります。

https://developer.sony.com/spresense/development-guides/sdk_developer_guide_ja.html#_%E3%82%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%82%AA%E3%82%B5%E3%83%96%E3%82%B7%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%83%A0%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6

この表を見ると、Code 0x6 はFIFOのオーバーフローですね。

ID: 0x06
Attension Code: AS_ATTENTION_SUB_CODE_SIMPLE_FIFO_OVERFLOW

おそらく log の計算に時間がかかりすぎて、音声処理が間に合わないのだと思います。試しに次のサンプルを Spresense で動かすと、759ミリ秒かかります。

```
#include <math.h>

const uint32_t array_size = 4096;
float data[array_size];
float output[array_size];

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);

  uint32_t start_time = 0;
  uint32_t duration = 0;
  
  /* initialize data */
  int value = 10;
  for (uint32_t n = 0; n < array_size; ++n) {
    data[n] = value;
    value += 10;
  }

  /* measure the time with log function */
  start_time = millis();
  for (uint32_t n = 0; n < array_size; ++n) {
    output[n] = log(data[n]);
  }
  duration = millis() - start_time;
  Serial.println("time(log): " + String(duration));
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

それに対し、サンプリングレート 48kHz で 4096 の音声サンプルを取り込む時間は、85ミリ秒です（1/48000 x 4096= 0.085）。つまり 85ミリ秒以内に処理をしないと次から次へとデータがやってきてしまい FIFO が溢れてしまいます。

私がよくやる解決策としては、4096のサンプルを別の配列にコピーして、コピーした配列をサブコアに渡して処理をするというものです。

Arduino IDE を使っているのなら、”ファイル”→”スケッチ例”→”Spresense用のスケッチ例”→"MultiCoreMP"→"AudioFFT" によい例があります。私はこのコードをいつも参考にしています。

Comment: マルチコアでの実装はかなり難しいと聞いていたので，取り掛かってはいなかったのですが，検討したいと思います．
また，別視点にはなりますが，logに入っていた値にかなり0に近いものがあり，そこに対策をしてあげるとAttentnionが出なくなりました．

Comment: 問題が回避できたようでよかったです。マルチコアはArduino IDEで実装できますし、簡単ですよ。ぜひチャレンジしてみてください。